# How to use Javascript to change pseudo element contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

I'm making a timeline website for practice and am trying to automatically update the pseudo elements to show the year on the timeline. I know I could do this targeting each nth-child, but there must be an easier way to do this using Javascript? I want to grab each year from each event using ID "yearGrab". I've written a comment in the CSS to show which bit I want to get changed to save you reading it all.

Please let me know using pure Javascript. Thanks!

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Vardana';
}

body {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(10,20,38,.96), rgba(26,49,75,.94));
 height: 100%;
}
.container {
 height: 650px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 font-size: 13px;
 cursor: grabbing;
}

#timelineList, li{
 width: max-content;
}

.timeline ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
 display: table-cell;
 max-width: none;
}

.timeline ul#timelineList:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 4px;
 background: white;
 margin-top: 306px;
}
/*NEXT TWO BITS ARE THE TARGET TO CHANGE WITH JAVASCRIPT*/
.timeline .EventOddDescription:after {
  content: '2019';
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 56px;
  bottom: -43.5px;
 border: 1.8px solid white;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(10,20,38,.9), rgba(26,49,75,.7));
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.timeline .EventEvenDescription:after {
  content: '';
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 17px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 56px;
  top: 49px;
 border: 1.8px solid white;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(10,20,38,.9), rgba(26,49,75,.7));
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.timeline .EventOddDescription:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
 left: 42px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 border-top: 14px solid white;
}
.timeline .EventEvenDescription:before {
 content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
 left: 42px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 14px solid white;
}

.timeline ul li div {
 background: white;
 margin-top: 94px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: black;
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 18px black;
}
.Category1 {
 display: block;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(101,78,163, 1)30%, rgba(101,78,163, .6));
 padding: 4px;
 margin: -10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.Category2 {
 display: block;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 65, 108, 1) 30%, rgba(255, 65, 108, .6));
 padding: 4px;
 margin: -10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 200;
}
.Category3 {
 display: block;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(253, 200, 48, 1)30%, rgba(253, 200, 48, .4));
 padding: 4px;
 margin: -10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 200;
}

.timeline ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  top: -18px;
}
.timeline div:nth-child(odd) {
 margin-right: -265px;
}
.timeline ul li:nth-child(even) {
  top: 247px;
 left: -80px;
}

.EventOddDescription {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.EventEvenDescription {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=“en”>
  <head>
 <title>Dads Website</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="JavaScript.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
          <h1>Pluto Timeline</h1>
    </header>

<section class="container">
  <div class="timeline">
    <ul id="timelineList">
      <li class="Event1">
        <div class="EventOddDescription">
          <p><span class="Category1">Category 1</span><br>
          <strong>Pluto Born</strong><br>
          <strong class="Year">03rd April <span id="yearGrab">2019</span></strong><br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.<a href="Event2More">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="Event2">
        <div class="EventEvenDescription">
          <p><span class="Category2">Category 2</span><br>
          <strong>Pluto's First Nap</strong><br>
          <strong class="Year">30th May 2020</strong><br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          <a href="Event2More">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
      </li>
        <li class="Event3">
          <div class="EventOddDescription">
            <p><span class="Category3">Category 3</span><br>
            <strong>Pluto's Second Nap</strong><br>
            <strong class="Year">03rd April 2020</strong><br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="Event3More">Read More</a></p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</section>



 </body>

 <footer class="footer">
 </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById('my-div')

myDiv.dataset.info = 'other info'
```

```css
#my-div::after { content : attr(data-info); color:red; }
```

```html
<div id="my-div" data-info="info" > blah blah blah </div>
```

to target a specific element:

```js
const myDivFirst_P = document.querySelector('#my-div p:first-child')

myDivFirst_P.dataset.info = ' info'
```

```css
#my-div p::after { content : attr(data-info); color:red; }
```

```html
 <div id="my-div">
  <p> the first<p>
  <p> the second<p>
  <p> the third<p>
</div>
```

what is the interest 200 lines of code for this question? is that minimal ?
please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My bad. New to coding & stack overflow. wanted to show the idea for the site to try and explain my question better.

Comment: @ParcGrowing Does my answer solve your problem, will you validate it?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not. I haven't made myself clear on what I was asking, sorry! I'm having trouble explaining what I require but that may be because what I want is not possible. I've decided to use an alternative approach. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand your question and i cant comment yet. so here's what i think you're asking about grabbing the year id from the html markup

in the html markup, i see

```
<span id="yearGrab">2019</span>
```

with js, you can do this

```
let yearGrab = getElementById('yearGrab')
yearGrab.innerText = 'whatever string you want'
```

Comment: Hi there! I want to copy the year '2019' within the yearGrab ID and make it appear in the 1st-child. But I want a way to do this throughout the content. so that the year shown in each timeline event is automatically pulled through to the relevant nth-child. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: sorry, still not clear what you're trying to do. can you pls add comment into your html markup what you like to extract and replace. thanks.